# After pseudoelement appear outside overflow-y ancestor

Tags: css, scroll, position, overflow, pseudo-element

I am trying to create a list of elements inside a wrapper container with overflow-y set to scroll. The problem is that I want each of these elements to have a tag appear on their right on hover.

This wrapper is inside of a vertical container with fixed width (cant be modified), which is used to align the wrapper with their siblings.

I am using an after pseudoelement to achieve this. The problem comes when I try to position the tag outside the wrapper container, which makes the tags not render.

Some example code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <p class="item" data-text="tag-1">
    item1
  </p>
  <p class="item" data-text="tag-2">
    item2
  </p>
  <p class="item" data-text="tag-3">
    item3
  </p>  
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  width: 10rem;
  height: 5rem;
  
  padding: 1rem;
  
  border: 1px solid red;
  
  overflow-y: scroll;
  
  
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.item{
  position: relative;
  
  font-size: 2rem
}

.item::before{
  content: "#";
  
}

.item::after{
  content:attr(data-text);
  
  position: absolute;
  
  top: 50%;
  left: 10rem;
  
  padding: 1rem;
  
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  
  border-radius: 500px;
  
  cursor: pointer;  
}
```

In this case I want the tags to appear outside the wrapper but positioned relative to their parent element. Is this posible to achieve using only css?

I tried using different positions, setting the overflow-x to visible and almost every answer I could find except using JS.